# Corona sound_decode triggered an error

Tags: audio, coronasdk, decode, playback

I'm receiving this message in loop at my console after I start my game:

> sound_decode triggered an error

The code that is triggering this is:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local introsound = audio.loadStream("sounds/intro.mp3")

-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local group = self.view

    local background = display.newRect(0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight)
    background.strokeWidth = 3
    background:setFillColor(170, 150, 170)
    background:setStrokeColor(0, 0, 0)

    local desliga = function (event)
        if event.completed then
            audio.stop()
            audio.dispose(introsound)
            introsound = nil
            print ("disposing")
        end
    end

    audio.play(introsound,{onComplete=desliga})
    -- audio.play(introsound)
```

Am I doing something wrong? or is it missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should not be loading the sound in the main chunk, and you probably shouldn't be playing it in the createScene() function.  I would consider doing all of them in enterScene() since you probably don't want your sound playing before your scene is on the screen.

You will have problems later when you re-enter the scene with loading the sound in the main chunk of the module and then disposing it.  But none of that has anything to do with this error.

Are there any other errors in the console log that might clue us in?

I would guess that particular error is probably related to a bad sound file.  Corona SDK only supports a 11,025 hz, 22Khz and 44Khz sounds. If your bit rate is different it might cause a problem.  The file could just be corrupt.  The "sound_decode" tells me it's having a problem decoding the sound which is where this error is likely.

Comment: Thank you Rob. Yesterday, I changed the sound file and it worked! Now that you are telling me about the pupported frequency, I'll take a look on that. Regards.

Comment: I have converted the sound using this free on line converter [link](http://online-audio-converter.com/) and now its working! Thank you.